# Dynamically remove null value from swift dictionary using function

Tags: ios, swift

I have following code for dictionary

```
var dic : [String: AnyObject] = ["FirstName": "Anvar", "LastName": "Azizov", "Website": NSNull(),"About": NSNull()]
```

I already remove key which have null value using below code

```
var keys = dic.keys.array.filter({dic[$0] is NSNull})
for key in keys {
  dic.removeValueForKey(key)
}
```

It works for static dictionary,But I want do it dynamically,I want to done it using function but whenever I pass dictionary as a argument it works as a let means constant so can not remove null key 
I make below code for that

```
func nullKeyRemoval(dic : [String: AnyObject]) -> [String: AnyObject]{
        var keysToRemove = dic.keys.array.filter({dic[$0] is NSNull})
        for key in keysToRemove {
            dic.removeValueForKey(key)
        }
        return dic
}
```

please tell me solution for this

Comment: func nullKeyRemoval(var dic : [String: AnyObject]) -> [String: AnyObject]{

Comment: Why you don't change your condition in filter function so you will get just the array with the data you want and you don't need to enumerate it again: ({!(dic[$0] is NSNull)})

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than using a global function (or a method), why not making it a method of `Dictionary`, using an extension?

```
extension Dictionary {
    func nullKeyRemoval() -> Dictionary {
        var dict = self

        let keysToRemove = Array(dict.keys).filter { dict[$0] is NSNull }
        for key in keysToRemove {
            dict.removeValue(forKey: key)
        }

        return dict
    }
}
```

It works with any generic types (so not limited to `String, AnyObject`), and you can invoke it directly from the dictionary itself:

```
var dic : [String: AnyObject] = ["FirstName": "Anvar", "LastName": "Azizov", "Website": NSNull(),"About": NSNull()]
let dicWithoutNulls = dic.nullKeyRemoval()
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5 adds `compactMapValues(_:)`, which would let you do

```
let filteredDict = dict.compactMapValues { $0 is NSNull ? nil : $0 }
```

Answer (score 3):

For `Swift 3.0 / 3.1` this could be helpful. Also removes `NSNull` objects recursive:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func nullKeyRemoval() -> [AnyHashable: Any] {
        var dict: [AnyHashable: Any] = self

        let keysToRemove = dict.keys.filter { dict[$0] is NSNull }
        let keysToCheck = dict.keys.filter({ dict[$0] is Dictionary })
        for key in keysToRemove {
            dict.removeValue(forKey: key)
        }
        for key in keysToCheck {
            if let valueDict = dict[key] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {
                dict.updateValue(valueDict.nullKeyRemoval(), forKey: key)
            }
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

Comment: Work, but just for embedded dictionaries that not contains embedded arrays

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3+:** Remove null from dictionary

```
 func removeNSNull(from dict: [String: Any]) -> [String: Any] {
    var mutableDict = dict
    let keysWithEmptString = dict.filter { $0.1 is NSNull }.map { $0.0 }
    for key in keysWithEmptString {
        mutableDict[key] = ""
    }
    return mutableDict
}
```

**Use**:

```
let outputDict = removeNSNull(from: ["name": "Foo", "address": NSNull(), "id": "12"])
```

Output: ["name": "Foo", "address": "", "id": "12"]

Answer (score 2):

## Nested `NSNull` supported

To remove **any** `NSNull` appearance in any nested level (including **arrays** and **dictionaries**), try this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String {
    func removeNullsFromDictionary() -> Self {
        var destination = Self()
        for key in self.keys {
            guard !(self[key] is NSNull) else { destination[key] = nil; continue }
            guard !(self[key] is Self) else { destination[key] = (self[key] as! Self).removeNullsFromDictionary() as? Value; continue }
            guard self[key] is [Value] else { destination[key] = self[key]; continue }

            let orgArray = self[key] as! [Value]
            var destArray: [Value] = []
            for item in orgArray {
                guard let this = item as? Self else { destArray.append(item); continue }
                destArray.append(this.removeNullsFromDictionary() as! Value)
            }
            destination[key] = destArray as? Value
        }
        return destination
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

A little more efficient than the other solutions. Uses only `O(n)` complexity.

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any? {

    var trimmingNullValues: [String: Any] {
        var copy = self
        forEach { (key, value) in
            if value == nil {
                copy.removeValue(forKey: key)
            }
        }
        return copy as [Key: ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Value>]
    }
}
```

`Usage: ["ok": nil, "now": "k", "foo": nil].trimmingNullValues // =
 ["now": "k"]`

If your dictionary is mutable you could do this in place and prevent the inefficient copying:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any? {
    mutating func trimNullValues() {
        forEach { (key, value) in
            if value == nil {
                removeValue(forKey: key)
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

`Usage: 
var dict: [String: Any?] = ["ok": nil, "now": "k", "foo": nil]
dict.trimNullValues() // dict now: = ["now": "k"]`

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do it, just 1 line

```
extension Dictionary {
    func filterNil() -> Dictionary {
        return self.filter { !($0.value is NSNull) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a global function (or a method), why not making it a method of Dictionary, using an extension?

```
   extension NSDictionary
    {
        func RemoveNullValueFromDic()-> NSDictionary
        {
            let mutableDictionary:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: self)
            for key in mutableDictionary.allKeys
            {
                if("\(mutableDictionary.objectForKey("\(key)")!)" == "<null>")
                {
                    mutableDictionary.setValue("", forKey: key as! String)
                }
                else if(mutableDictionary.objectForKey("\(key)")!.isKindOfClass(NSNull))
                {
                    mutableDictionary.setValue("", forKey: key as! String)
                }
                else if(mutableDictionary.objectForKey("\(key)")!.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary))
                {
                    mutableDictionary.setValue(mutableDictionary.objectForKey("\(key)")!.RemoveNullValueFromDic(), forKey: key as! String)
                }
            }
            return mutableDictionary
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you use `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` in `Swift` when they have native counterparts? Function names should also start with lowercase letters. Moreover, there are a lot of forced unwrapping that could crash the code and this answer only works with `String` keys.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 example using reduce

```
let dictionary = [
  "Value": "Value",
  "Nil": nil
]

dictionary.reduce([String: String]()) { (dict, item) in

  guard let value = item.value else {
    return dict
  }

  var dict = dict
  dict[item.key] = value
  return dict
}
```