# Generic Swift Dictionary Extension for nil filtering

Tags: swift, dictionary, generics, swift3

I'm looking for a type safe, generic version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647940/4239752).

This is the method signature I'm looking for:

```
extension Dictionary where Value == Optional<T> {
    func filterNil() -> <Key, T>
}
```

Is there any way to express this in Swift 3?

**Edit:**

My motivation for creating a Dictionary with optional values is that I need something like this:

```
struct User {
    var mail: String?
    var name: String?

    func marshaled() -> [String: Any] {
        return [
            "mail": mail,
            "name": name
        ].filterNil()
    }
}
```

I much prefer the dictionary literal to creating an empty dictionary and filling the values manually.

Comment: Optional dictionary values are nonsensical anyway. By definition a `nil` value means *key is missing*. It is much more efficient to declare all dictionaries with non-optional values. Then you can fix the issue(s) at **compile time**.

Comment: I get your point and agree with you. I edited the answer to state my motivations for having `Optional` values. 

Maybe I'll overload the dictionary literal initializer to filter `nil` values.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/43356680/2976878

Comment: It's easier to declare the members in `User` as non-optional. Most likely in practice every user will require a name and a mail address.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks, this is golden

Comment: @vadian That was just an example to make my problem obvious. My real struct is slightly more complex.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** As of **Swift 5** this would be:

```
let filtered = dict.compactMapValues { $0 }
```

**Update:** As of **Swift 4,** you can simply do

```
let filtered = dict.filter( { $0.value != nil }).mapValues( { $0! })
```

It is [currently being discussed](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-add-compactmapvalues-to-dictionary/8741) if `Dictionary` should get 
a `compactMapValues` method which combines `filter` and `mapValues`.

---

(*Previous answer:*)
You can use the same "trick" as in [How can I write a function that will unwrap a generic property in swift assuming it is an optional type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563161/how-can-i-write-a-function-that-will-unwrap-a-generic-property-in-swift-assuming/34575096#34575096) and [Creating an extension to filter nils from an Array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190631/creating-an-extension-to-filter-nils-from-an-array-in-swift/30892122#30892122): 
define a protocol to which all optionals conform:

```
protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    func intoOptional() -> Wrapped?
}

extension Optional : OptionalType {
    func intoOptional() -> Wrapped? {
        return self
    }
}
```

Then your dictionary extension can be defined as:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: OptionalType {
    func filterNil() -> [Key: Value.Wrapped] {
        var result: [Key: Value.Wrapped] = [:]
        for (key, value) in self {
            if let unwrappedValue = value.intoOptional() {
                result[key] = unwrappedValue
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let dict = ["mail": nil, "name": "John Doe"] // Type is [String : String?]
let filtered = dict.filterNil() // Type is [String : String]
print(filtered) // Output: ["name": "John Doe"]
```

Comment: I can't get to write an extension on Dictionary using your Swift 4 update. `OptionalType` doesn't seem to be a thing anymore and `extension Dictionary where Value: Optional` is illegal. Did you manage to do so?

Comment: @Performat: Which Xcode version are you using? Everything compiles in my Xcode 9.2 (with Swift language version set to 4.0) – But actually you don't need a dictionary extension for Swift 4, it can be done with filter/mapValues alone, as demonstrated in the first code block.

Comment: My bad, I just realize you declared `OptionalType` as a proxy. Everything compiles when using your first solution. I was looking for a way to reach the same result without using `OptionalType`. Using `extension Dictionary where Value == Optional<AnyHashable>`, I lose the type, so this isn't optimal either.

Comment: @Performat: Then you can use the extension method from the older answer, it still works in Swift 4.

Comment: @Performat: Yes, the "problem" is that you cannot restrict `Value` to a generic type like `Optional`.

Comment: Love that Swift is making these pain points progressively nicer!