# How to make sure dictionary doesn't contain nil values

Tags: ios, swift

I have a dictionary that could contain nil values:

```
let dict : [String : Any?] = [
    "firstName": firstName,
    "surname": surname, // could be nil
    "bio": bio, // could be nil
    "createdAt": timestamp
]
```

I want to filter out all these nil values. I've tried this:

```
let newDict = dict.filter { $0.value != nil }
```

but that still returns as `[String : Any?]`. How can I make it return as `[String : Any]`?

Update:
Turns out that it's counted as `Any?` because there are optionals in it. I need to be able to unwrap all optionals in the dictionary.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456812/generic-swift-dictionary-extension-for-nil-filtering.

Comment: @MartinR That worked, thank you!

Comment: Actually it is simpler in Swift 4, I have update the other answer.